# Google Data (Python) library not installing correctly?

Tags: windows-7, installation, python

I'm following the directions [here](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/write-google-spreadsheet-from-python/) to get some example code up and running using Google's API to write to a spreadsheet and I don't think gdata is installing correctly. When I run `python setup.py install` I get one warning about install_requires being an unknown distribution option (despite having easy_install properly installed) but it seems to install correctly. Here's the output:

```
C:\gdata\gdata>python setup.py install
C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option:
 'install_requires'
  warnings.warn(msg)
running install
running build
running build_py
copying src\atom\auth.py -> build\lib\atom
copying src\atom\client.py -> build\lib\atom
copying src\atom\core.py -> build\lib\atom
copying src\atom\data.py -> build\lib\atom
copying src\atom\http.py -> build\lib\atom
copying src\atom\http_core.py -> build\lib\atom
copying src\atom\http_interface.py -> build\lib\atom
copying src\atom\mock_http.py -> build\lib\atom
copying src\atom\mock_http_core.py -> build\lib\atom
copying src\atom\mock_service.py -> build\lib\atom
copying src\atom\service.py -> build\lib\atom
copying src\atom\token_store.py -> build\lib\atom
copying src\atom\url.py -> build\lib\atom
copying src\atom\__init__.py -> build\lib\atom
copying src\gdata\apps_property.py -> build\lib\gdata
copying src\gdata\auth.py -> build\lib\gdata
copying src\gdata\client.py -> build\lib\gdata
copying src\gdata\core.py -> build\lib\gdata
copying src\gdata\data.py -> build\lib\gdata
copying src\gdata\gauth.py -> build\lib\gdata
copying src\gdata\sample_util.py -> build\lib\gdata
copying src\gdata\service.py -> build\lib\gdata
copying src\gdata\test_config.py -> build\lib\gdata
copying src\gdata\test_data.py -> build\lib\gdata
copying src\gdata\urlfetch.py -> build\lib\gdata
copying src\gdata\__init__.py -> build\lib\gdata
copying src\gdata\Crypto\test.py -> build\lib\gdata\Crypto
copying src\gdata\Crypto\__init__.py -> build\lib\gdata\Crypto
copying src\gdata\Crypto\Cipher\__init__.py -> build\lib\gdata\Crypto\Cipher
copying src\gdata\Crypto\Hash\HMAC.py -> build\lib\gdata\Crypto\Hash
copying src\gdata\Crypto\Hash\MD5.py -> build\lib\gdata\Crypto\Hash
copying src\gdata\Crypto\Hash\SHA.py -> build\lib\gdata\Crypto\Hash
copying src\gdata\Crypto\Hash\__init__.py -> build\lib\gdata\Crypto\Hash
copying src\gdata\Crypto\Protocol\AllOrNothing.py -> build\lib\gdata\Crypto\Prot
ocol
copying src\gdata\Crypto\Protocol\Chaffing.py -> build\lib\gdata\Crypto\Protocol

copying src\gdata\Crypto\Protocol\__init__.py -> build\lib\gdata\Crypto\Protocol

copying src\gdata\Crypto\PublicKey\DSA.py -> build\lib\gdata\Crypto\PublicKey
copying src\gdata\Crypto\PublicKey\ElGamal.py -> build\lib\gdata\Crypto\PublicKe
y
copying src\gdata\Crypto\PublicKey\pubkey.py -> build\lib\gdata\Crypto\PublicKey

copying src\gdata\Crypto\PublicKey\qNEW.py -> build\lib\gdata\Crypto\PublicKey
copying src\gdata\Crypto\PublicKey\RSA.py -> build\lib\gdata\Crypto\PublicKey
copying src\gdata\Crypto\PublicKey\__init__.py -> build\lib\gdata\Crypto\PublicK
ey
copying src\gdata\Crypto\Util\number.py -> build\lib\gdata\Crypto\Util
copying src\gdata\Crypto\Util\randpool.py -> build\lib\gdata\Crypto\Util
copying src\gdata\Crypto\Util\RFC1751.py -> build\lib\gdata\Crypto\Util
copying src\gdata\Crypto\Util\test.py -> build\lib\gdata\Crypto\Util
copying src\gdata\Crypto\Util\__init__.py -> build\lib\gdata\Crypto\Util
copying src\gdata\acl\data.py -> build\lib\gdata\acl
copying src\gdata\acl\__init__.py -> build\lib\gdata\acl
copying src\gdata\alt\appengine.py -> build\lib\gdata\alt
copying src\gdata\alt\app_engine.py -> build\lib\gdata\alt
copying src\gdata\alt\__init__.py -> build\lib\gdata\alt
copying src\gdata\analytics\client.py -> build\lib\gdata\analytics
copying src\gdata\analytics\data.py -> build\lib\gdata\analytics
copying src\gdata\analytics\service.py -> build\lib\gdata\analytics
copying src\gdata\analytics\__init__.py -> build\lib\gdata\analytics
copying src\gdata\apps\apps_property_entry.py -> build\lib\gdata\apps
copying src\gdata\apps\client.py -> build\lib\gdata\apps
copying src\gdata\apps\data.py -> build\lib\gdata\apps
copying src\gdata\apps\service.py -> build\lib\gdata\apps
copying src\gdata\apps\__init__.py -> build\lib\gdata\apps
copying src\gdata\apps\adminsettings\service.py -> build\lib\gdata\apps\adminset
tings
copying src\gdata\apps\adminsettings\__init__.py -> build\lib\gdata\apps\adminse
ttings
copying src\gdata\apps\audit\service.py -> build\lib\gdata\apps\audit
copying src\gdata\apps\audit\__init__.py -> build\lib\gdata\apps\audit
copying src\gdata\apps\emailsettings\client.py -> build\lib\gdata\apps\emailsett
ings
copying src\gdata\apps\emailsettings\data.py -> build\lib\gdata\apps\emailsettin
gs
copying src\gdata\apps\emailsettings\service.py -> build\lib\gdata\apps\emailset
tings
copying src\gdata\apps\emailsettings\__init__.py -> build\lib\gdata\apps\emailse
ttings
copying src\gdata\apps\groups\client.py -> build\lib\gdata\apps\groups
copying src\gdata\apps\groups\data.py -> build\lib\gdata\apps\groups
copying src\gdata\apps\groups\service.py -> build\lib\gdata\apps\groups
copying src\gdata\apps\groups\__init__.py -> build\lib\gdata\apps\groups
copying src\gdata\apps\migration\service.py -> build\lib\gdata\apps\migration
copying src\gdata\apps\migration\__init__.py -> build\lib\gdata\apps\migration
copying src\gdata\apps\multidomain\client.py -> build\lib\gdata\apps\multidomain

copying src\gdata\apps\multidomain\data.py -> build\lib\gdata\apps\multidomain
copying src\gdata\apps\multidomain\__init__.py -> build\lib\gdata\apps\multidoma
in
copying src\gdata\apps\organization\client.py -> build\lib\gdata\apps\organizati
on
copying src\gdata\apps\organization\data.py -> build\lib\gdata\apps\organization

copying src\gdata\apps\organization\service.py -> build\lib\gdata\apps\organizat
ion
copying src\gdata\apps\organization\__init__.py -> build\lib\gdata\apps\organiza
tion
copying src\gdata\blogger\client.py -> build\lib\gdata\blogger
copying src\gdata\blogger\data.py -> build\lib\gdata\blogger
copying src\gdata\blogger\service.py -> build\lib\gdata\blogger
copying src\gdata\blogger\__init__.py -> build\lib\gdata\blogger
copying src\gdata\books\data.py -> build\lib\gdata\books
copying src\gdata\books\service.py -> build\lib\gdata\books
copying src\gdata\books\__init__.py -> build\lib\gdata\books
copying src\gdata\calendar\client.py -> build\lib\gdata\calendar
copying src\gdata\calendar\data.py -> build\lib\gdata\calendar
copying src\gdata\calendar\service.py -> build\lib\gdata\calendar
copying src\gdata\calendar\__init__.py -> build\lib\gdata\calendar
copying src\gdata\calendar_resource\client.py -> build\lib\gdata\calendar_resour
ce
copying src\gdata\calendar_resource\data.py -> build\lib\gdata\calendar_resource

copying src\gdata\calendar_resource\__init__.py -> build\lib\gdata\calendar_reso
urce
copying src\gdata\codesearch\service.py -> build\lib\gdata\codesearch
copying src\gdata\codesearch\__init__.py -> build\lib\gdata\codesearch
copying src\gdata\contacts\client.py -> build\lib\gdata\contacts
copying src\gdata\contacts\data.py -> build\lib\gdata\contacts
copying src\gdata\contacts\service.py -> build\lib\gdata\contacts
copying src\gdata\contacts\__init__.py -> build\lib\gdata\contacts
copying src\gdata\contentforshopping\client.py -> build\lib\gdata\contentforshop
ping
copying src\gdata\contentforshopping\data.py -> build\lib\gdata\contentforshoppi
ng
copying src\gdata\contentforshopping\__init__.py -> build\lib\gdata\contentforsh
opping
copying src\gdata\docs\client.py -> build\lib\gdata\docs
copying src\gdata\docs\data.py -> build\lib\gdata\docs
copying src\gdata\docs\service.py -> build\lib\gdata\docs
copying src\gdata\docs\__init__.py -> build\lib\gdata\docs
copying src\gdata\dublincore\data.py -> build\lib\gdata\dublincore
copying src\gdata\dublincore\__init__.py -> build\lib\gdata\dublincore
copying src\gdata\exif\__init__.py -> build\lib\gdata\exif
copying src\gdata\finance\data.py -> build\lib\gdata\finance
copying src\gdata\finance\service.py -> build\lib\gdata\finance
copying src\gdata\finance\__init__.py -> build\lib\gdata\finance
copying src\gdata\geo\data.py -> build\lib\gdata\geo
copying src\gdata\geo\__init__.py -> build\lib\gdata\geo
copying src\gdata\health\service.py -> build\lib\gdata\health
copying src\gdata\health\__init__.py -> build\lib\gdata\health
copying src\gdata\media\data.py -> build\lib\gdata\media
copying src\gdata\media\__init__.py -> build\lib\gdata\media
copying src\gdata\notebook\data.py -> build\lib\gdata\notebook
copying src\gdata\notebook\__init__.py -> build\lib\gdata\notebook
copying src\gdata\oauth\rsa.py -> build\lib\gdata\oauth
copying src\gdata\oauth\__init__.py -> build\lib\gdata\oauth
copying src\gdata\opensearch\data.py -> build\lib\gdata\opensearch
copying src\gdata\opensearch\__init__.py -> build\lib\gdata\opensearch
copying src\gdata\photos\service.py -> build\lib\gdata\photos
copying src\gdata\photos\__init__.py -> build\lib\gdata\photos
copying src\gdata\projecthosting\client.py -> build\lib\gdata\projecthosting
copying src\gdata\projecthosting\data.py -> build\lib\gdata\projecthosting
copying src\gdata\projecthosting\__init__.py -> build\lib\gdata\projecthosting
copying src\gdata\sites\client.py -> build\lib\gdata\sites
copying src\gdata\sites\data.py -> build\lib\gdata\sites
copying src\gdata\sites\__init__.py -> build\lib\gdata\sites
copying src\gdata\spreadsheet\service.py -> build\lib\gdata\spreadsheet
copying src\gdata\spreadsheet\text_db.py -> build\lib\gdata\spreadsheet
copying src\gdata\spreadsheet\__init__.py -> build\lib\gdata\spreadsheet
copying src\gdata\spreadsheets\client.py -> build\lib\gdata\spreadsheets
copying src\gdata\spreadsheets\data.py -> build\lib\gdata\spreadsheets
copying src\gdata\spreadsheets\__init__.py -> build\lib\gdata\spreadsheets
copying src\gdata\tlslite\api.py -> build\lib\gdata\tlslite
copying src\gdata\tlslite\BaseDB.py -> build\lib\gdata\tlslite
copying src\gdata\tlslite\Checker.py -> build\lib\gdata\tlslite
copying src\gdata\tlslite\constants.py -> build\lib\gdata\tlslite
copying src\gdata\tlslite\errors.py -> build\lib\gdata\tlslite
copying src\gdata\tlslite\FileObject.py -> build\lib\gdata\tlslite
copying src\gdata\tlslite\HandshakeSettings.py -> build\lib\gdata\tlslite
copying src\gdata\tlslite\mathtls.py -> build\lib\gdata\tlslite
copying src\gdata\tlslite\messages.py -> build\lib\gdata\tlslite
copying src\gdata\tlslite\Session.py -> build\lib\gdata\tlslite
copying src\gdata\tlslite\SessionCache.py -> build\lib\gdata\tlslite
copying src\gdata\tlslite\SharedKeyDB.py -> build\lib\gdata\tlslite
copying src\gdata\tlslite\TLSConnection.py -> build\lib\gdata\tlslite
copying src\gdata\tlslite\TLSRecordLayer.py -> build\lib\gdata\tlslite
copying src\gdata\tlslite\VerifierDB.py -> build\lib\gdata\tlslite
copying src\gdata\tlslite\X509.py -> build\lib\gdata\tlslite
copying src\gdata\tlslite\X509CertChain.py -> build\lib\gdata\tlslite
copying src\gdata\tlslite\__init__.py -> build\lib\gdata\tlslite
copying src\gdata\tlslite\integration\AsyncStateMachine.py -> build\lib\gdata\tl
slite\integration
copying src\gdata\tlslite\integration\ClientHelper.py -> build\lib\gdata\tlslite
\integration
copying src\gdata\tlslite\integration\HTTPTLSConnection.py -> build\lib\gdata\tl
slite\integration
copying src\gdata\tlslite\integration\IMAP4_TLS.py -> build\lib\gdata\tlslite\in
tegration
copying src\gdata\tlslite\integration\IntegrationHelper.py -> build\lib\gdata\tl
slite\integration
copying src\gdata\tlslite\integration\POP3_TLS.py -> build\lib\gdata\tlslite\int
egration
copying src\gdata\tlslite\integration\SMTP_TLS.py -> build\lib\gdata\tlslite\int
egration
copying src\gdata\tlslite\integration\TLSAsyncDispatcherMixIn.py -> build\lib\gd
ata\tlslite\integration
copying src\gdata\tlslite\integration\TLSSocketServerMixIn.py -> build\lib\gdata
\tlslite\integration
copying src\gdata\tlslite\integration\TLSTwistedProtocolWrapper.py -> build\lib\
gdata\tlslite\integration
copying src\gdata\tlslite\integration\XMLRPCTransport.py -> build\lib\gdata\tlsl
ite\integration
copying src\gdata\tlslite\integration\__init__.py -> build\lib\gdata\tlslite\int
egration
copying src\gdata\tlslite\utils\AES.py -> build\lib\gdata\tlslite\utils
copying src\gdata\tlslite\utils\ASN1Parser.py -> build\lib\gdata\tlslite\utils
copying src\gdata\tlslite\utils\cipherfactory.py -> build\lib\gdata\tlslite\util
s
copying src\gdata\tlslite\utils\codec.py -> build\lib\gdata\tlslite\utils
copying src\gdata\tlslite\utils\compat.py -> build\lib\gdata\tlslite\utils
copying src\gdata\tlslite\utils\Cryptlib_AES.py -> build\lib\gdata\tlslite\utils

copying src\gdata\tlslite\utils\Cryptlib_RC4.py -> build\lib\gdata\tlslite\utils

copying src\gdata\tlslite\utils\Cryptlib_TripleDES.py -> build\lib\gdata\tlslite
\utils
copying src\gdata\tlslite\utils\cryptomath.py -> build\lib\gdata\tlslite\utils
copying src\gdata\tlslite\utils\dateFuncs.py -> build\lib\gdata\tlslite\utils
copying src\gdata\tlslite\utils\hmac.py -> build\lib\gdata\tlslite\utils
copying src\gdata\tlslite\utils\jython_compat.py -> build\lib\gdata\tlslite\util
s
copying src\gdata\tlslite\utils\keyfactory.py -> build\lib\gdata\tlslite\utils
copying src\gdata\tlslite\utils\OpenSSL_AES.py -> build\lib\gdata\tlslite\utils
copying src\gdata\tlslite\utils\OpenSSL_RC4.py -> build\lib\gdata\tlslite\utils
copying src\gdata\tlslite\utils\OpenSSL_RSAKey.py -> build\lib\gdata\tlslite\uti
ls
copying src\gdata\tlslite\utils\OpenSSL_TripleDES.py -> build\lib\gdata\tlslite\
utils
copying src\gdata\tlslite\utils\PyCrypto_AES.py -> build\lib\gdata\tlslite\utils

copying src\gdata\tlslite\utils\PyCrypto_RC4.py -> build\lib\gdata\tlslite\utils

copying src\gdata\tlslite\utils\PyCrypto_RSAKey.py -> build\lib\gdata\tlslite\ut
ils
copying src\gdata\tlslite\utils\PyCrypto_TripleDES.py -> build\lib\gdata\tlslite
\utils
copying src\gdata\tlslite\utils\Python_AES.py -> build\lib\gdata\tlslite\utils
copying src\gdata\tlslite\utils\Python_RC4.py -> build\lib\gdata\tlslite\utils
copying src\gdata\tlslite\utils\Python_RSAKey.py -> build\lib\gdata\tlslite\util
s
copying src\gdata\tlslite\utils\RC4.py -> build\lib\gdata\tlslite\utils
copying src\gdata\tlslite\utils\rijndael.py -> build\lib\gdata\tlslite\utils
copying src\gdata\tlslite\utils\RSAKey.py -> build\lib\gdata\tlslite\utils
copying src\gdata\tlslite\utils\TripleDES.py -> build\lib\gdata\tlslite\utils
copying src\gdata\tlslite\utils\xmltools.py -> build\lib\gdata\tlslite\utils
copying src\gdata\tlslite\utils\__init__.py -> build\lib\gdata\tlslite\utils
copying src\gdata\webmastertools\data.py -> build\lib\gdata\webmastertools
copying src\gdata\webmastertools\service.py -> build\lib\gdata\webmastertools
copying src\gdata\webmastertools\__init__.py -> build\lib\gdata\webmastertools
copying src\gdata\youtube\client.py -> build\lib\gdata\youtube
copying src\gdata\youtube\data.py -> build\lib\gdata\youtube
copying src\gdata\youtube\service.py -> build\lib\gdata\youtube
copying src\gdata\youtube\__init__.py -> build\lib\gdata\youtube
running install_lib
running install_egg_info
Removing C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\gdata-2.0.17-py2.7.egg-info
Writing C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\gdata-2.0.17-py2.7.egg-info
```

Attempting to run the sample code previously linked to results in the following:

```
C:\gdata>python gdata.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gdata.py", line 4, in <module>
    import gdata.spreadsheet.service
  File "C:\gdata\gdata.py", line 4, in <module>
    import gdata.spreadsheet.service
ImportError: No module named spreadsheet.service
```

But interestingly, if I simply run `python` from the command line and tap out the offending line - `import gdata.spreadsheet.service` - it works perfectly fine, which is why I'm guessing this is an install/config issue rather than a code issue.

Python 2.7 on Windows 7, if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be an install question to which [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10686196/819417) is the answer:

`python setup.py` uses distutils which doesn't support install_requires. setuptools does, but also distribute (its successor) and pip (which basically uses either setuptool/distribute) do. But you actually have to use them. I.e. call setuptools through the `easy_install` command or `pip install`. Another way is to import setup from setuptools in your setup.py, but this not standard and makes everybody wanting to use your package to have setuptools installed.

Comment: adding `from setuptools import setup` has resolved the error during the setup process, but I still get `ImportError: No module named spreadsheet.service` when running gdata.py. Again, I can import spreadsheet.service via the interpreter but not in a script. Any ideas?

Comment: Try `import spreadsheet.service` instead of `import gdata.spreadsheet.service`, as gdata.py is already in your gdata folder.

Comment: Same error... I'm quite confused as to what could be wrong...

Comment: What do the [tests](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/source/browse/#hg%2Ftests) and [samples](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/source/browse/#hg%2Fsamples) say from a minimal file with a less confusing name and location? Maybe your Python path is getting broken somehow.

Comment: Running all tests in module gdata_tests.spreadsheet_test
...........
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 11 tests in 0.009s

OK

Comment: The above is the result from the spreadsheet_test portion of all tests. There weren't any errors in the other modules either. I can't figure out how it could possibly pass any test though when a py file containing only one line importing the spreadsheet service errors out...

Comment: I'd try their Wiki and file an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/issues/list) if needed.